# Heroku Git says "up to date " but it is not updating

Tags: git, heroku, git-push

Background: When it was time for me to apply changes.  I applied this first:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a ewbudget
$ cd ewbudget
```

Instead of updating it merely with:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

I have read that I should check to see if I am on master branch and I am but for some reason I am still have trouble updating my new code.

Comment: what messages are output that indicate "trouble updating"?

Comment: When I check my app, its still rendering my old code.  Also when I try ```git releases``` the last update doesn't match

Comment: `heroku git:clone` looks like a cloning operation, while `git add. + push` is very much the opposite. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app). You downloaded old content instead of uploading new content, maybe?

Comment: I believe by me ```heroku git:clone``` first, it messed up the process.  However, I am not to familiar with Git, so I am stuck from here.

Comment: Have you read these https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push ?

Comment: what did you do to check you were on the master branch?

Comment: [`heroku git:clone` shouldn't be part of your regular workflow](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub."

Comment: What does "for some reason I am still have trouble updating my new code" mean? Please read [ask]. We need as much detail as possible, ideally as a [mcve]. What are the exact commands that you're running? What files are you changing? What errors, if any, are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, now I updated my code of an already running app like this:

```
git commit -am "your-message"
git push heroku
```